# How to tell EXIST to look also in the path directories in windows batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm trying to do this simple thing on windows but it always fail and i think that the cause is that it's not looking in the PATH variable, how should i do?

```
IF EXIST lessc.cmd (
    lessc --yui-compress bootstrap.less > ../css/bootstrap.min.css
) ELSE (
    echo Error: lessc not found. Install Node.js then: npm install -g less
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Windows version probably has `where.exe`:

```
where /q lessc || (
    echo Errrrror.
    goto :eof
)

lessc --yui-compress bootstrap.less > ../css/bootstrap.min.css
```

The `||` operator works like in Linux *sh*; its opposite is `&&`.

---

For older versions:

```
:havecomm
  set "comm=%~$PATH:1"
  goto :eof
```

Whenever you call it with `call :havecomm lessc`, it will set `%comm%` to its full path, or empty if not found.

If you don't know the exact extension and want to check all possibilities, the longer version will work:

```
:havecomm
  set comm=
  if not "%~$PATH:1"=="" (
    set "comm=%~$PATH:1"
  ) else (
    for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do (
      for %%i in (%1%%e) do (
        if not "%%~$PATH:i"=="" (
          set "comm=%%~$PATH:i"
          goto :eof
  ))))
  goto :eof
```